# How to read serial COM port and separate values?

Tags: python, serial-port, readline, pyserial

I have a device here that sends serial data and I want to read serial data, it is a simple format and I have to separate the values to be useful so I can post process these.

Serial data in terminal view:

[image]

I tried a lot of things for reading like `readline()`, `read_until(b'\r')`... but I could not get anything that works line does not know when the line ends because of `\r` and `read_until` does just random things and does not stop at the `\r` for some reason.

Results from `print(ser.read_until(b'\r').hex())`:

[image]

Also I don't know how I would separate the values either.
A bit of info to the data there are 6 different Values indicated by the 4th and 5th byte 70, 71, ... and then the bytes 8 to 15 is the number in ascii.
I just want this 16 byte serial data separated into for example `int`s for doing math later on.

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

for i in range(10):
    print("read_until()" + ser.read_until(b'\r',16).hex())
    time.sleep(1)
    print("read(16)" + ser.read(16).hex())
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()
```

results from the program

```
read_until()0d
read(16)0204023731000030303030303030300d
read_until()02
read(16)04033732000030303030303030300d02
read_until()04
```

Comment: Where's your code? What module are you using to read and write the serial data? Please [edit] your question and add this missing information.

Comment: Please check the specifications of the device you are using. It should describe the format of the data notified by the device.

Comment: There are no specifications @kunif, there is not much code beside opening the com port and printing out the Data but i can ad that

Comment: @martineau thanks for the edit, first time doing such thing

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what third-party library / module you're using — Python doesn't have a built-in one for doing this. Also the output you show with the "results from the program" looks bogus because it couldn't have been generated by the preceding code. As for the format of the data from the device, you _must_ figure this out some way — either by looking at the raw data or determining it is some other way — perhaps you can get the specs from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: @martineau oh i thought this was obvious there is only one i know of called "serial" pyserial. The result is just literally copied from the terminal not all 10 Interation but i dont think there would be any point to it. The raw data is shown above from the terminal. There are unfortunately no specification or interface documentation but it is quite simple as you can see in the Image.

Comment: I asked because pySerial doesn't have a `read_until()` function. Its `readline()` function looks for newline (`'\n'`) characters not carriage-returns (`'\r'`) which is what the `0x0D` byte is.

Comment: @martineau read_until() is described here https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html, exactly why readline does not work for this, because it is terminated with ('\r')

Comment: I was looking at the documentation of an older version (3.0) of the module I googled which apparently was before the `read_until()` was added. Regardless, iit's unclear why the `ser.read_until(b'\r')` doesn't work — try `ser.read_until('\r')`. If that doesn't work either, you can always process the bytes manually and look for the carriage-return line endings.

Comment: Thanks, yes also tried 'ser.read_until('\r')' yield similar results, i will go forward and do it in my own function.

Comment: @Heinzinich Unfortunately, I don't understand what your actual question is. Reading the data seems to work. Do you want to learn how to store are value into a variable and access that value?